# ASP.NET MVC AntiForgeryToken and AdSense Crawler Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, adsense

I have a website with content served behind a login. I want to add Google AdSense to the protected pages, but Google claims that the AdSense Crawler will need its own login to perform proper crawling. [See here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/161351?hl=en&ref_topic=1348129).

So, I setup a username/password for the crawler, put in the POST parameters to Google's settings page, but then realized that this won't work in my login configuration because ASP.NET MVC uses an AntiForgeryToken to protect against cross site attacks. How can I setup a login for the AdSense Crawler when my site specifically forbids cross site logins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need xsrf protection on login. So remove it. The places that it's actually useful is when you're updating deleting or adding data. Using xsrf protection doesn't actually serve much benefit on login.

Here's a scenario it would be useful to implement, imagine your're logged into your online banking account, and a site posts data to transfer money from your account to elsewhere... Those are the kind of scenarios where it's actually valuable to use xsrf tokens.

On login however, the attacker would have to know the password let alone the token and if the attacker does know the password, then your token is useless anyway